# Nginx location regex for css and js

Tags: regex, nginx, nginx-location, nginx-reverse-proxy

As my configuration, I'd like to serve css and js in location /luz_online_web, only access to /luz_online_web/*.css or .js is proxy_pass to http://110.134.0.20:8085/luz_online_web/.

```
server {
    server_name ~(?<name>[^.]+)\.dev\.abc\.io$;
    location  / {
      proxy_pass http://110.134.0.20:8085/luz_online_web/$name$request_uri;
      include /etc/nginx/klara-reverse.conf;

    }
    location ~* ^/luz_online_web/(.+\.(css|js))$ {
        rewrite ^/luz_online_web/(.*)$ /luz_online_web/$1 break;
        proxy_pass http://110.134.0.20:8085;
    }
}
```

But css and js file still not be loaded when I access to website. 
CSS, JS file located in /luz_online_web directory while other files(HTML,PNG..) stored in /luz_online_web/name directory. If I remove filter and set location /luz_online_web/, they could be loaded, the path of js file such as

`/luz_online_web/javax.faces.resource/jsf.js;jsessionid=SnhEULxbunZ9F6OEGRtJrMmy`

[image]

Any idea?

Comment: so what is the difference between normal HTML files and CSS/JS files? seems both get from proxy. Can you elaborate?

Comment: @JonnieJS: normal html files could be load from luz_online_web/$name while css/js need to be load from luz_online_web folder.

Comment: and it is the **same** directory. please try to explain me where exactly every resource is located.
Please make edits for your question and try to add as many details as possible. Thanks.

Comment: @JonnieJS: it not the same. CSS, JS file located in /luz_online_web directory while other files(HTML,PNG..) stored in /luz_online_web/name directory. I just updated my question.

Comment: Can you please provide one example to css file path, and one example to png file path? it seems to me it is the same.

Answer (score 0):

My issue is solved, I remove $ at the end of regex location, due to .css and .js in between of URL instead of the end.

```
location ~* ^/luz_online_web/(.+\.(css|js)) {
    rewrite ^/luz_online_web/(.*) /luz_online_web/$1 break;
    proxy_pass http://110.134.0.20:8085;
}
```